# How to get unique ID for emails in outlook to be able to search and retrieve later?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

It is troublesome to memo the subject for every important email and sometimes even the subject may be the same for different emails. Is there way to extract a unique ID from emails I received in outlook which is searchable when trying to retrieve the email?

Comment: The unique email ID is in the Outlook Headers. Outlook Email, and then Properties of the email.

Comment: how I can get Id of the outlook email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each message has a Message-ID header, Usually this ID is assigned by the sender's mail app. The Message-ID is also used for combining threads.
To view the Message-ID:

1. Double-click an email message to open it outside of the Reading Pane.
2. Click File > Properties, then locate the message headers in the Internet headers area.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m5Oa.png)

Message-ID is indeed a unique identifier for each message,but you can't search a message by its Message-ID.
More information about Message header in this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/540820/understanding-microsoft-message-id-email-header.html

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.